# how to get data from a popup in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get data entered in the popup on click button but it retrieve undefined values for the enter data any help please.

```
<modal title="Login form" name="modaloption" ng-model="modaloption" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </modal>
```

script:

```
 $scope.submit = function(){
    console.log("testing button");
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    console.log("email:"+$scope.email);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said where this modal directive came from, and where it's documented, but presumably, it defines its own scope, meaning that the name and password populated by ng-model are in the modal directive scope, and not in the controller scope. That's also what happens when using ng-model inside ng-if or ng-repeat.

Make sure to have this line of code in your controller:

```
$scope.modalState = {};
```

and in the view, use

```
ng-model="modalState.email"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working properly, see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dotywy1j/1/

This prints out exactly what I have entered from the input fields. The problem that you can encounter is that the input tag for email doesn't store the actual value unless it's a **valid email.** (something@something.com)

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
```